# Oracle SQL update from one Table to another table throws syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL update from one Table to another table throws syntax error for following simple update query.

```
UPDATE Sales_Import SI
SET AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
WHERE RAN.LeadID = SI.LeadID;
```

**Error:**

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
Error at Command Line:2 Column:37
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

I believe the same query will work in other databases like postgres etc.

Could any one tell the correct query ?

and whatever i tried is this ANSI standard query ?

Comment: why do you have multiple database product tags? How is this question related to Oracle or mysql or blah blah blah other than teradata?

Comment: @LalitKumarB : I tagged other DB since i need ansi standard query which is common to other dbs .. how would you achieve this in oracle in ANSI format ? The same will work in teradata

Comment: @LalitKumarB : I have changed my question after executing in oracle. It throws same error. I have updated this question as well with respect to oracle so that everyone can have a look at it...

Comment: No, that is not standard SQL. ANSI SQL does not allow for any joins to be used in an `UPDATE` (or `DELETE`)  statement.

Comment: `UPDATE 
(SELECT table1.accountno as OLD, table2.accountno as NEW
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.LeadID  = table2.LeadID 
) temp
SET temp.OLD = temp.NEW`
Try This one with Inner Join

Comment: @NagendraNigade, You might, but only if Oracle allows the inline view to be updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and whatever i tried is this ANSI standard query ?

No. Oracle Oracle doesn't support join in update statement.

In Oracle you could do it in two ways  -

**Merge statement **

with only **update clause** in merge statement

```
MERGE INTO sales_import s   
USING (SELECT * 
       FROM   retrieveaccountnumber) u 
ON (u.leadid = s.leadid) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET u.accountnumber = s.accountnumber;
```

**Correlated query**

```
UPDATE sales_import t1
   SET accountnumber  = (SELECT t2.accountnumber  
                         FROM retrieveaccountnumber t2
                        WHERE t1.leadid = t2.leadid )
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM retrieveaccountnumber t2
     WHERE t1.leadid = t2.leadid );
```

Comment: Thanks. How about inner join one ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support a direct join in update statement. You could use the Merge or the correlated query. You could also use an inline view, let me add it to the answer as well.

Comment: what if dont use `WHERE EXISTS` in correlated query ? remaining query also will give same answer right ?

Comment: can you answer me for above comment to accept your anser ?

Comment: The where exists will restrict the unmatched rows. The filter predicate takes care of considering only those rows in source table for which there exists rows in other table.

Comment: If you remove the exits clause, it will update all the rows. That's not what you want, you want to update only those rows which match the join condition.

Answer (score 2):

I will write your sql like this:

```
UPDATE Sales_Import SI
SET AccountNumber = (Select RAN.AccountNumber
                 FROM RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
                 WHERE RAN.LeadID = SI.LeadID);
```

Comment: it would fail if the subquery returns more than single row.

Comment: @LalitKumarB : Then how to handle ? how we can restrict multiple values ? your answer also does not give that option

Comment: Restricting values can be done by filters. Try using more filters depending on your situation.

Comment: No. Adding filter is different than updating ONLY those rows which satisfy the join condition. Your query will update all the rows in table Sales_Import. But, you are not supposed to do that. Take a simple example, and test yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining those tables:

```
UPDATE SI
SET AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
JOIN Sales_Import SI ON RAN.LeadID = SI.LeadID;
```

Comment: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`

Comment: Yes, sorry. That wont work in Oracle. Seems like you can not do this by joining in Oracle. Very strange and ugly..

Comment: Oracle does not support join in update statement. You could use Merge, see my answer.